# Compute covariance changing monthly business days over 6 months Matlab

Tags: matlab, frequency, covariance, moving-average

Can you please help me with the following:
I want to compute the covariance between 2 returns each month, by averaging out the returns over the past 6 months, using an exponentially weighted moving average.

Please find below the formula:

[image: \frac{T_t}{6} \frac{\sum_{\tau=1}^{T_t} \delta^{T_t - \tau} (r_{d,i,\tau} - \bar{r}_{d,i,t}) (r_{d,j,\tau} - \bar{r}_{d,j,t})}{\sum_{\tau=1}^{T_t} \delta^{T_t - \tau}}]

$T_t$ is the number of trading days within the past 6 months

$\delta$ is the decaying factor (weight) and equal to 0.95

$r_{d,i,\tau}$ is the daily return of asset i on day $\tau$ in the 6 month period preceding the last day of month $t$

[image: \bar{r}_{d,i,t}=\frac{1}{T_t}\sum_{\tau=1}^{T_t}r_{d,i,\tau}] is the sample average of the daily returns over the past 6 months

I don't know how to set up this problem in order to account for the exact number of trading days within a month or for the 6 months preceding period.

The data matrix contains the dates on first column and various returns on the subsequent columns.

Please find below a snapshot

```
Columns 1 through 6

    'dates:  (8609)'    'series 1:  (8609)'    'series 2:  (8609)'    'series 3:  (8609)'    'series 4:  (8609)'    'series 5:  (8609)'
    '01-Jan-1985'       [           0.8254]    [           0.7567]    [           0.3842]    [           0.6206]    [           1.1587]
    '02-Jan-1985'       [           0.8162]    [           0.7563]    [           0.3818]    [           0.6163]    [           1.1485]
    '03-Jan-1985'       [           0.8160]    [           0.7572]    [           0.3812]    [           0.6187]    [           1.1515]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please show an attempt to solve the problem, otherwise it seems that you are asking us to do the job for you. Read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I wanted to construct a for loop, but I don't know how to account for the changing business days within a month and how to select the one 6 months before in order to be precise. If you have any suggestion of a function in mind, please let me know and I will provide my attempt. I tried with an average of 21 business days, but the results are not exact since the actual number of business days may vary. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have access to the financial toolbox?

Comment: Yes, I have access to the financial toolbox.